# Como manipular um elemento HTML criado pelo Template literals?

Tags: template

Alguém sabe porque quando você cria um componente HTML usando o Template literals ele retorna sempre null? ex: criei uma lista e quero pegar as li pra colocar um evento, mas sempre me retorna null, sendo que ela existe no DOM.

```
const $container = doc.querySelector('[data-js="container"]');
const $categorie = doc.querySelectorAll('[data-js="categorie"] li');

 const markup = `
    <ul data-js='categorie'>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
    </ul>
 `;

 $container.innerHTML = markup;
```

Comment: Obs: A lista se torna um nodeList e daria pra transformar em array like com a feature do es6 o Array.from() sem problemas, mas a zica é que o elemento criado pelo template literals não existe no DOM.

Answer (score 0):

O seu problema está na ordem da execução, você deve executar a busca pelos elementos, após eles serem criados no *DOM*, coloque essa linha:

```
const $categorie = doc.querySelectorAll('[data-js="categorie"] li');
```

Abaixo desta:

```
$container.innerHTML = markup;
```

#### Exemplo

```js
const doc = document;
const $container = doc.querySelector('[data-js="container"]');

const markup = `
    <ul data-js='categorie'>
      <li>item 01</li>
      <li>item 02</li>
      <li>item 03</li>
    </ul>
`;

$container.innerHTML = markup;

const $categorie = doc.querySelectorAll('[data-js="categorie"] li');

Array.from($categorie).forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        alert("Você clicou em: " + this.innerText);
    });
});
```

```html
<div data-js="container"></div>
```

Comment: Wellingthon, 
Obrigado! era isso mesmo, valeu mesmo, perdi o dia nisso ontem..  
Valeu!!!

Comment: Se possível marque como certa ou útil.